# Why are DocuSign CustomFields not deserializing from envelope?

Tags: xml, docusignapi

Just this past week, our tests against the DocuSign demo API are failing.  We've traced it to a Custom Field in a local DocuSignEnvelopeInformation class that appears to have been auto-generated when the functionality was first put into place.  This class is part of a return call from DocuSign that has been in place for years.

The Custom Field has four properties.  The xml has started coming in with the nodes in a different order than they normally would, and is causing the deserialization into a local Custom Field class to fail.

It may be that all I need to do is remove the "Order=.." in the xml serialization attribute.  But I'm curious to know why this would suddenly not work.  We noticed this problem on 2/19/2020.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was reported previously and it was due to a bug in our demo environment, the fix was released yesterday 2/23. By now this should not be causing any issues anymore.